# Divide child records into clusters by record count without splitting parent id

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis

I'm trying to build a process to split a group of transactions into roughly equal sized groups to facilitate chunking the data.

An entity can have multiple transactions. For the sake of this question, let's say a transaction can have multiple amounts associated with it. That's nonsense, but it keeps everything numeric.

I want to divide up the total transactions into clusters, but I can't divide an entity. All of an entity's transactions need to be processed together.

Here's a sample data set:

```
CREATE TABLE #sorting
(
 Entity_ID bigint
,Trans_ID bigint
,Trans_Amt money
);

INSERT #sorting
(
 Entity_ID 
,Trans_ID 
,Trans_Amt 
)
VALUES
  (321, 456, 1.00),
  (321, 457, 2.00),
  (5309, 458, 10.00),
  (321, 459, 1.50),
  (5309, 460, 2.50),
  (321, 461, 10.50),
  (5309, 462, 3.00),
  (321, 463, 4.00),
  (321, 465, 6.00),
  (867, 466, 7.00),
  (321, 467, 9.00),
  (867, 466, 22.00),
  (321, 468, 4.20)

SELECT
  Entity_ID
  ,COUNT(*) AS RecCnt
FROM #sorting
GROUP BY Entity_ID;

SELECT 
  *
FROM #sorting
ORDER BY 
 Entity_ID 
,Trans_ID 
,Trans_Amt DESC;


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#sorting', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #sorting;
```

The result set of the first query looks like this:

```
Entity_ID   RecCnt
  321         8
  867         2
 5309         3
```

My dream result set looks like this (it doesn't need the record count, just the Entity_ID and group membership. Record count is included for the explanation that follows):

```
Entity_ID   RecCnt  Group_ID
  321         8         1
  867         2         2
 5309         3         2
```

Entity_ID 321 is in a group by itself, since it contains over half of the transactions. Entity_IDs 867 and 5309 are clustered together because their total transactions are, more or less, equal to the total in 321.

In real life, I'm splitting a few million transactions into, probably, 8 or 10 clusters.

I've tried different permutations of NTILE() and a few unsuccessful sub queries, but I think I've gotten myself in too deep. If anyone can lend a hand, I'd be most appreciative.

EDIT: 20180223 - Changed the goal from parallel processing to data chunking.

Comment: This sounds like a typical XY Problem to me. http://xyproblem.info/ Parallel processing isn't going to make this any faster which I am guessing is what you are trying to accomplish. Maybe if you share the business issue you are trying to solve we can help you find a food way of handling it.

Comment: This is odd.  Where are you gong to parallel process?  If you are doing it in SQL then it will parallel itself.   If you are going to do it in .NET then a producer consumer pattern could be used.

Comment: @SeanLange was spot on, though in fairness I admitted that I was in too deep. Taking some time to step back was the right thing to do. The actual problem I'm trying to fix is that the process I've been tasked with trouble shooting keeps filling up tempdb. While I'm still esoterically interested in the question I posed, it's not the solution to my problem. Should I take the question down? I feel like I should. (Plus, I never should've said "parallel". Sorry about that.)

Comment: If you are filling up tempdb it is often a sign that the size of your transaction is too large. Maybe you need to chunk your data? Maybe that is where this started?

Comment: @SeanLange, exactly that. The chunk boundaries can't cross entity_ids, but some entities have hundreds of thousands of transactions, while others only have single digits.

Comment: Why can't you process rows across entity_ids? I have seen that kind of thing said before but it turns out the hurdle was not finding a solution worked across boundaries. It all boils down to what the problem is.

Comment: Part of the processing involves allocating payments across the all of the trans_ids for each entity_id, and the payments are pulled in by entity_id. So (absent a full rewrite) each entity_id has to be pulled in it's entirety by the chunking component.

Answer (score 1):

The question looks similar to this
[Split set of values into 5 groups each group should have sum(count) evenly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46992210/split-set-of-values-into-5-groups-each-group-should-have-sumcount-evenly/47004755#47004755)

I changed my answer from this question according to your question.

```
DECLARE @GroupCount INT = 2

;WITH Data AS (
    SELECT
      Entity_ID
      ,COUNT(*) AS RecCnt
    FROM #sorting
    GROUP BY Entity_ID
),
CTE AS (
    SELECT * ,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RecCnt DESC)
    FROM Data
)
,CTE2 AS (
    SELECT *, 
        RN2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CEILING( RN / @GroupCount * 1.0 ), (( 1 - CEILING( RN / @GroupCount * 1.0 )) * RecCnt ) DESC ) 
    FROM CTE 
)
SELECT 
    CTE2.Entity_ID, 
    CTE2.RecCnt, 
    ((RN2+1) % @GroupCount) +1 GroupIndex, 
    SUM(CTE2.RecCnt) OVER (PARTITION BY ((RN2+1) % @GroupCount)) CmlTotal 
FROM CTE2
```